# CXF 3.1 RESTful Client Using JAXB Error: SEVERE: No message body reader has been found for class

Tags: jaxb, cxf, unmarshalling

I'm new to CXF and JAXB.  I'm having problems with a RESTful client that calls a external web service.  I think I've followed the steps necessary to do this but I'm getting the following error when executing the client:

SEVERE: No message body reader has been found for class com.jaxb.AcXML, ContentType: text/html
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: No message body reader has been found for class com.jaxb.AcXML, ContentType: text/html
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.reportMessageHandlerProblem(ResponseImpl.java:433)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.doReadEntity(ResponseImpl.java:384)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.readBody(AbstractClient.java:512)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.handleResponse(WebClient.java:1173)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doResponse(WebClient.java:1156)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doChainedInvocation(WebClient.java:1092)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:894)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:865)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.invoke(WebClient.java:428)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.get(WebClient.java:611)
    at com.ws.GetOpenPO.getOpenPOs(GetOpenPO.java:58)
    at com.ws.GetOpenPO.main(GetOpenPO.java:79)

My IDE is Eclipse Indigo.  I've created a Dynamic Web Project and included the CXF 2.x Web Services, JAX-RS and JAXB facets.  Below is the class I'm testing with:

```
package com.ws;

import java.text.MessageFormat;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit;
import org.apache.cxf.transports.http.configuration.HTTPClientPolicy;

import com.jaxb.AcXML;

 public class GetOpenPO {

 private String baseUrl;

 public AcXML getOpenPOs(  )
    {
        // Create a WebClient pointing to the base URL of the RESTful web service

        WebClient client = WebClient.create( baseUrl ).path("GetOpenPOs");          
        HTTPConduit http = WebClient.getConfig(client).getHttpConduit();
        HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy=new HTTPClientPolicy();
        httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(1000000);
        httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(1000000);
        httpClientPolicy.setProxyServer("proxy1.global.mycompany.com");
        httpClientPolicy.setProxyServerPort(8080);
        http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);

        // Set the path from which we wish to get the object, request XML, and use JAXB

       AcXML POs= client.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                                            .query("U", "parm1")
                                            .query("P", "parm2")
                                            .query("N", "parm3")
                                            .query("Processed", "parm4")
                                            .query("StationEnd", "")
                                            .get( AcXML.class);

        return POs;
    }

    public String getBaseUrl()
    {
        return baseUrl;
    }

    public void setBaseUrl( String baseUrl )
    {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    }


    public static void main(String args[]){

        GetOpenPO  x = new GetOpenPO ();
        x.setBaseUrl("http://www24.externalws.net/webservices/webservices.asmx");

        AcXML openPOs = x.getOpenPOs(); 
    }
}
```

I was able to call the webservice via my browser, which returns an XML document.  Using this XML I created a schema and then using the "JAXB Classes from Schema" wizard in Eclipse the JAXB objects were generated.  Below is the source file for the AcXML entity that I'm trying to retrieve via the client:

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.4-2 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2015.08.05 at 10:18:48 AM EDT 
//


package com.jaxb;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element ref="{https://www.externalws.net/acXMLSchema.xsd}Header"/>
 *         &lt;element ref="{https://www.externalws.net/acXMLSchema.xsd}Request"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *       &lt;attribute name="lang" use="required">
 *         &lt;simpleType>
 *           &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}    string">
 *           &lt;/restriction>
 *         &lt;/simpleType>
 *       &lt;/attribute>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
  * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "header",
    "request"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "acXML")
public class AcXML {

@XmlElement(name = "Header", required = true)
protected Header header;
@XmlElement(name = "Request", required = true)
protected Request request;
@XmlAttribute(name = "lang", required = true)
protected String lang;

/**
 * Gets the value of the header property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link Header }
 *     
 */
public Header getHeader() {
    return header;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the header property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link Header }
 *     
 */
public void setHeader(Header value) {
    this.header = value;
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the request property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link Request }
 *     
 */
public Request getRequest() {
    return request;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the request property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link Request }
 *     
 */
public void setRequest(Request value) {
    this.request = value;
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the lang property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public String getLang() {
    return lang;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the lang property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public void setLang(String value) {
    this.lang = value;
}
```

}

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or what am I missing that's causing the client to fail?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Add JAXBProvider

```
List<JAXBElementProvider> list = new ArrayList<JAXBElementProvider>();
list.add(new JAXBElementProvider());
WebClient client = WebClient.create( baseUrl, list).path("GetOpenPOs");
```

Comment: Karthik- thanks for the response.  I added the code you suggested but I'm still receiving the same error.  I also noticed that when the client is executed it fails intermittently with a different exception:

Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error

Then eventually it executes and throws the original exception that I asked about: "No message body reader has been found for class...."

Not sure if this intermittent exception is contributing to the original problem or not.

Comment: I've also tested a different CXF/JAXB client using the same logic but for a different RESTful service.  The XML returned by that service is much simpler and the code is the same except for the endpoint, querry() parms and  and object specified in the .get() method.  This other client executed successfully without the intermittent HTTP 500 exception

Comment: It seems some problem with server side, even though you set the accept to application/xml your server returns with content-type  text/html. check the content types provided by server for this uri